# Element-wise addition of 1D and 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

### Situation

I have objects that have attributes which are represented by numpy arrays:

```
>> obj = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
```

where `1`, `2`, `3` are the attributes' values.

I'm about to write a few methods that should work equally on *both* a single object and a group of objects. A group of objects is represented by a 2D numpy array:

```
>>> group = numpy.array([[11, 21, 31],
...                      [12, 22, 32],
...                      [13, 23, 33]])
```

where the first digit indicates the object and the second digit indicates the attribute. That is `12` is attribute 2 of object 1 and `21` is attribute 1 of object 2.

**Why this way and not transposed?** Because I want the array indices to correspond to the attributes. That is `object_or_group[0]` should yield the first attribute either as a single number or as a numpy array, so it can be used for further computations.

Alright, so when I want to compute the dot product for example this works out of the box:

```
>>> obj = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> obj.dot(object_or_group)
```

What doesn't work is element-wise addition.

Input:

```
>>> group
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> obj
array([10, 20])
```

The resulting array should be the sum of the first element of `group` and `obj` and similar for the second element:

```
>>> result = numpy.array([group[0] + obj[0],
...                       group[1] + obj[1]])
>>> result
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

However:

```
>>> group + obj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)
```

Which makes sense considering numpy's [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

It seems that there is no numpy function which performs an addition (or equivalently the broadcasting) along a specified axis. While I could use

```
>>> (group.T + obj).T
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

this feels very cumbersome (and if, instead of a group, I consider a single object this feels wrong indeed). Especially because numpy covered each and every corner case for its usage, I have the feeling that I might have gotten something conceptually wrong here.

### To sum it up

Similarly to

```
>>> obj1
array([1, 2])
>>> obj2
array([10, 20])
>>> obj1 + obj2
array([11, 22])
```

(which performs an element-wise - or attribute-wise - addition) I want to do the same for groups of objects:

```
>>> group
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

while the layout of such a 2D group array must be such that the single objects are listed along the 2nd axis (`axis=1`) in order to be able to request a certain attribute (or many) via normal indexing: `obj[0]` and `group[0]` should both yield the first attribute(s).

Comment: I think you need to think about what dimensions are used for what really carefully. It actually makes a lot of sense that `group[0]` is the first object in `group`. `group[:, 0]` is the first attribute of all the objects in group. If you need to distinguish a group from an object, just check its `ndim` attribute. Groups will have 2, objects will have 1.

Comment: Well that's the point. I don't want to distinguish between groups and objects from the method's point of view. It should work for single objects and behave similarly for groups without the need for explicit checks. Say one method should return the square of the first attribute, then this is simply `obj_or_group[0] ** 2` without being required to check for dimensions. I want to achieve the same for addition, say a method that should return all attributes plus some attribute vector. I thought one major purpose of numpy is to allow for similar equations when going to higher dimensions.

Comment: You could always specify `axis=-1` for calls like `np.sum`.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have sums but additions. Consider a `(2, 4)` matrix and a `(2,)` vector. I want to add the two _row-wise_, i.e. the first row in the matrix should be added the first vector element and the second matrix row the second vector element (and so on for higher dimensions). This is not what numpy does. Due to numpy's broadcasting mechanism it will add column-wise. I would like to know if there's a way (other than `(matrix.T + vector).T`) to add the matrix and the vector. Is this conceptually wrong (when going to higher dimensions maybe)? I don't see why it would be though.

Comment: `(group.T + obj).T` does not work if the operands are obj and obj. This whole concept is very much flawed.

Comment: What is dot supposed to represent?

Comment: What? `(obj1.T + obj2).T` won't work for `obj1` and `obj2` being 1d arrays? I suggest you give it a try and prove yourself wrong. Transposition is a no-op for 1d arrays. `dot` means the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: `(obj1.T + obj2).T` will work just fine. Try `(group.T + obj).T` where group is a `(2, 3)` and `obj` is a `(3,)` array.

Comment: I did not fully understand what you were trying to do when I wrote that comment. Please ignore the second part of it.

Answer (score 4):

what you want to do seems to work with this simple code !!

```
>>> m
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> g = np.array([10,20])
>>> m + g[ : , None]
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confused about which dimension of the matrix is an object and which is an attirbute, as evidenced by the changing object size in your examples. In fact, it it the fact that you are swapping dimensions to match that changing size that is throwing you off. You are also using the unfortunate example of a 3x3 group for your dot product, which is further throwing off your explanation.

In the examples below, objects will be three-element vectors, i.e., they will have three attributes each. The example group will have consistently two rows, meaning two objects in it, and three columns, because objects have three attributes.

The first row of the group, `group[0]`, a.k.a. `group[0, :]`, will be the first **object** in the group. The first column, `group[:, 0]` will be the first **attribute**.

Here are a couple of sample objects and groups to illustrate the points that follow:

```
>>> obj1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> obj2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
>>> group1 = np.array([[7, 8, 9],
                      [0, 1, 2]])
>>> group2 = np.array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

Addition will work out of the box because of broadcasting now:

```
>>> obj1 + obj2
array([5, 7, 9])
>>> group1 + obj1
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
       [ 1,  3,  5]])
```

As you can see, corresponding attributes are getting added just fine. You can even add together groups, but only if they are the same size or if one of them only contains a single object:

```
>>> group1 + group2
array([[10, 12, 14],
       [ 3,  5,  7]])
>>> group1 + group1
array([[14, 16, 18],
       [ 0,  2,  4]])
```

The same will be true for all the binary elementwise operators: `*`, `-`, `/`, `np.bitwise_and`, etc.

The only remaining question is how to make dot products not care if they are operating on a matrix or a vector. It just so happens that dot products don't care. Your common dimension is always the number of attributes, so the second operand (the multiplier) needs to be transposed so that the number of columns becomes the number of rows. `np.dot(x1, x2.T)`, or equivalently `x1.dot(x2.T)` will work correctly whether `x1` and `x2` are groups or objects:

```
>>> obj1.dot(obj2.T)
32
>>> obj1.dot(group1.T)
array([50,  8])
>>> group1.dot(obj1.T)
array([50,  8])
```

You can use either [`np.atleast_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) or [`np.atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) to always coerce the result into a particular shape so you don't end up with a scalar like the `obj1.dot(obj2.T)` case. I would recommend the latter, so you always have a consistent number of dimensions regardless of the inputs:

```
>>> np.atleast_2d(obj1.dot(obj2.T))
array([[32]])
>>> np.atleast_2d(obj1.dot(group1.T))
array([[50,  8]])
```

Just keep in mind that the dimensions of the dot product will be the the number of objects in the first operand by the number of objects in the second operand (everything will be treated as a group). The attributes will get multiplied and summed together. Whether or not that has a valid interpretation for your purposes is entirely for you to decide.

**UPDATE**

The only remaining problem at this point is attribute access. As stated above `obj1[0]` and `group1[0]` mean very different things. There are three ways to reconcile this difference, listed in the order that I personally prefer them, with 1 being the most preferable:

1. Use the `Ellipsis` indexing object to get the last index instead of the first

   ```
   >>> obj1[..., 0]
   array([1])
   >>> group1[..., 0]
   array([7, 0])
   ```

   This is the most efficient way since it does not make any copies, just does a normal index on the original arrays. As you can see, there will be no difference between the result from a single object (1D array) and a group with only one object in it (2D array).
2. Make all your objects 2D. As you pointed out yourself, this can be done with a decorator, and/or using `np.atleast_2d`. Personally, I would prefer having the convenience of using 1D arrays as single objects without having to wrap them in 2D.
3. Always access attributes via a transpose:

   ```
   >>> obj1.T[0]
   1
   >>> group1.T[0]
   array([7, 0])
   ```

   While this is functionally equivalent to #1, it is clunky and unsightly by comparison, in addition to doing something very different under-the-hood. This approach at the very least creates a new view of the underlying array, and may run the risk of making unnecessary copies in certain cases if the group arrays are not laid out just right. I would not recommend this approach even if it does solve the problem if uniform access.

Comment: You might have a point here, using the transposed layout while making sure that arrays are always 2d implies consistency across the application. Ensuring that arrays are always 2d could be realized by a decorator, `numpy.atleast_2d` seems a very interesting option here. Not sure yet if I'll go this way but this is definitely a promising suggestion.

Comment: I had forgotten about making attribute access uniform. Thanks for the reminder. Added an update with a better (as in using numpy more efficiently without giving up convenience) solution than 2D arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the update, using `...` seems nice indeed. However there is a subtle difference in using this syntax for an `obj` and a `group` which contains one object. `obj[..., 0]` returns `array(0)` while `group[..., 0]` returns `array([0])`. For that reason (regarding consistency) I would rather go with #2. As mentioned using a decorator it's fine having 1-axis objects which become wrapped in a 2-axis group before they are passed to the actual method (and then converted back to 1-axis upon return).

Comment: Anyway I think it's a trade-off for both group layouts (objects being stored row-wise or column-wise). Using row-wise storage (as proposed by you) one can apply _per attribute_ modifications in a straightforward way (`group + attribute_vector`) however _per object_ modifications require some twists (e.g. adding a number which is different for each object to all attributes of that object; needs to be something like `(group.T + object_vector).T` or equivalently `group + object_vector[:, None]`).

Comment: @a_guest. Try to stay away from `.T` as much as possible unless the operation is already expensive, like `dot`. Hopefully my answer has shown that you can treat both objects and groups the same for any given operation as long as you play with the notation a little bit.

Comment: In the end I'm going to use an array which stores the objects column-wise (i.e. one object per column) because I actually don't need to distinguish between objects but only apply collective operations on them. That said I would never use `group[0]` for row-wise storage however for column-wise storage this will be a frequent feature. In addition I will enforce usage of 2-axis arrays only (no single objects _within_ methods; decorators where needed). Anyway your answer provided quite some insight, thanks! P.S.: I don't see why transposing an array should be a costly operation.

Comment: @a_guest. Not especially costly by itself if you do it once or twice, but it can sometimes require a copy, which can add significantly to runtime if you do it often on large arrays.